# Where to store CSRF token - ViewState or Session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, csrf

I've been looking into the [CSRF](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eWEgUcHPle0) vulnerability and how to fix it in .NET application.

Based on my research here is the pseudo algorithm I need to do:

1. Check request for CSRF token in the request cookie, if it is not there, create one
   on the server.
2. Once the token is created, add the token to the
   response cookie to send back to client. Client sends this CSRF
   token for all future request cookie.
3. When server receives a request and it
   sees the CSRF cookie, the server validates against its stored CSRF
   token value.
4. When it matches, then business as usual, if the values
   don't match then stop the request.

My question is in step #3, I'm using ASP .NET web form;  I can store this CSRF token in either Session or a ViewState.

I don't want to use ViewState because all the pages in our application have to support EnableViewState="true".  If not, the ViewState content is wiped out on each and every post-back call.

Can I use Session in this situation? Does it compromise the fix if I use Session instead of ViewState?

Comment: I don't think validating cookie without some other information from client side will provide protection... You may want to review https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Prevention…

Comment: Alexei, feel free to correct me if I mistaken but isn't this covered in the step #1 and #2? the server generate a csrf token, send it back to the client in the form of cookie, the client the use that cookies in all subsequent request.

Comment: ASP.NET Web Forms has this built in. It is stored in a hidden field.

Comment: I don't know - inventing or validating security measures on my own is not something I ever do (just totally not my area) so I always concern when people try to do so and always stick to recommended practices in my code. You probably can find some discussions by https://www.bing.com/search?q=csrf+why+checking+cookie+not+enough (or similar searches).

Comment: Note that cookies will be sent in requests from another origin as well, thus a csrf token in a cookie will not provide any protection against csrf (unless compared to a value also sent by the client but not in a cookie, see double posting). Please read up and understand the problem first, before trying to solve it with a custom solution. Or just use `AntiForgery` as noted below.

Comment: Hi Gabor, I thank you for giving your input;  though I want to show you that I did my research and the way I understand it you are implying about making sure about Cross Site Scripting - XSS.  I did not come up with this custom solution, I merely summarize it based on the article I found it at https://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/developer-guide-csrf  which recommends by owasp.org and I am trying to ask a question here to gain more insight about that solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're going for the [Synchronizer token pattern (STP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Synchronizer_token_pattern) technique, using a single token per user session.

There's no problem in using the ASP .NET session storage for saving CSRF tokens, based on the trivial assumption that the attacker has no access to it, this doesn't compromise your solution in any way. Nonetheless, as pointed out in [Gabor Lengye's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60937980/where-to-store-csrf-token-viewstate-or-session#comment107816564_60937980), using cookies to send the CSRF token to the server is flawed, embed the token in an HTML form instead, or use the [Cookie-to-header token](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Cookie-to-header_token) technique.

That said, I suggest you take a look at the [AntiForgery Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.helpers.antiforgery?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2) which has built-in token generation, HTML embedding and validation methods. Security wise it's never a good idea to implement your own solution, instead go for established, trusted solutions.

Also make sure to use HTTPS to prevent your tokens from being hijacked in a [Sniffing attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sniffing_attack)

Comment: Thank you Thomas, for answering my original question, I'll use AntiForgery as per Gabor, Heretic and your recommendation.